# Android reboots permanent after i activated OBB Move in Link2SD, data is aviable

Tags: boot-loop, crashes, link2sd

I activated *OBB Move* in the Link2SD app (I don't know exactly what it does, but I already asked the developer, he hasn't answered yet)  and then I had to reboot. After I rebooted the system worked properly, but after a minute it said "Process `system` has stopped" and then it rebooted. After reboot I could use my system, all data was available, but about a minute later it again said "Process `system`has stopped". This results into an endless loop.

Is there any way to solve this problem? And if I have to reset the system is there any way to save important data?

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 LTE (SM-T805), Android 5.0.2, rooted with KingRoot.

Comment: **PROBLEM SOLVED:** After i **rejected root permissons** for Link2SD and **deleted app i tried move to sd** my android works  properly.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! On SE sites, it's perfectly fine to [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question), even [our help center states so](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). So would you mind posting your solution as answer, and then accept that answer? That helps other users in similar situations to identify solutions. Thanks!